# Office Outlook add-in (web) how to know if new mail arrive

Tags: outlook, office365, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to develop an add-in in office outlook where add-in should automatically read incoming emails and process my logic to it. I have developed the functionality when I have to specifically click the email to process my logic. But I want the functionality where the add-in should automatically process all incoming emails without manually clicking them.

Have implemented below points as of now:

1. outlook pinnable task pane
2. Item Changed Event

```
Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, ItemChanged);
function ItemChanged(eventArgs) {
   /*code*/
}
```

Comment: replaced outlook-addin tag with outlook-web-addins

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. The addins are tied to the item in the view and hence the item needs to be selected for the add-in to work on. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.